# Error 'tunneling socket' while executing npm install

Tags: npm, protractor

I'm getting the error shown below while trying to execute 'npm install' command.

> Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 10.232.207.137:8080

What do I miss?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 90):

If you are behind a proxy, set it correctly in npm.

```
>npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
>npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
```

**Notes:**

1. For SSL/https proxies, the protocol in URL should be **http** not **https**
2. If your set up is on a Docker/Vagrant instance or a hosted VM, use IP address instead of hostname for proxy as the later might not be resolvable.
3. If there is no proxy , remove proxy config from npm

   ```
   >npm config set proxy null
   >npm config set https-proxy null
   ```

Comment: `npm config set proxy null npm config set https-proxy null` save me. Thanks!

Comment: after setting npm config set proxy null i am getting Error:Invalid Protocol :null

Comment: Setting proxies to null, as suggested in the last steps, worked for me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: `npm config delete proxy`is the correct way to clear unnecessary configurations.

Comment: `For SSL/https proxies, the protocol in URL should be http not https` I had no idea this was the case. And what is worst, other apps seem to be able to deal with `https` just fine.

Comment: Thanks for that, the https/http thing was what was broken for me. That's irritatingly inconsistent.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is way too late but if someone has a similar issue in the future and you are sure you have `no proxy set` but you have an environment variable called **http_proxy**. Please delete it and try again. I had set a proxy for Fiddler.

Comment: Welcome, Glad I helped

Comment: No Problem, Cheers Saeed

Comment: Been banging my head so long. totally forgot about the environment variable. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I too spent a week trying to figure the issue out before I came across this - thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

according to [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2472) it's proxy isssues, try to disable ssl and set registry to http instead of https . hope it helps!

```
npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: Saved the day, it's a issue that proxy not allowing to create tunnels it seems.

Answer (score 13):

Following commands may solve your issue:

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```

It solved my same issue.

Comment: close the proxy function of npm works for me! thanks.

Comment: I got this unhelpful message on the second command:
"npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one."

Answer (score 7):

**Removing the proxy settings resolved the issue:**

If you are no using any proxy:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

If you are using Proxy:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxyhostname:proxyport
npm config set https-proxy https://proxyhostname:proxyport
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Wow, Add proxies, remove proxies, null proxies.
Crazy!
Nothing works.

Answer (score 7):

In my case helped delete .npmrc config file

```
rm ~/.npmrc
```

Comment: This helped me as well. I am behind corporate proxy.. But deleting npmrc worked..

Answer (score 4):

remember to set you username and password if required:

http://USERNAME:passwd@proxyserver.co.uk:8080

Example:

```
npm config set proxy http://USERNAME:passwd@proxyserver.co.uk:8080
```

Answer (score 4):

If in case you are using ubuntu trusty 14.0 then search for Network and select Network Proxy and make it none. Now proxy may still be set in system environment variables. check

```
env|grep -i proxy
```

you may get output as

```
http_proxy=http://192.168.X.X:8080/
ftp_proxy=ftp://192.168.X.X:8080/
socks_proxy=socks://192.168.X.X:8080/
https_proxy=https://192.168.X.X:8080/
```

unset these environment variable as:

```
unset(http_proxy)
```

and in this way unset all. Now run npm install ensuring user must have permission to make node_modules folder where you are installing module.

Answer (score 3):

Next to what has described @Roshith in his [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892578/1306012):

> If you are behind a proxy, set it correctly in npm.
>
> ```
> npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
> npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
> ```

I had to change also the file `~.bashrc` which also contained a wrong proxy setting in my case. I changed those settings here:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxyhost:proxyport"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxyhost:proxyport"
```

Use the following command to verify the proxy settings:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

Comment: Yes, `npm config` is the config of npm; `~/.bashrc` is the config of your bash env

Answer (score 1):

An important point to remember is if you're behind a corporate firewall and you get you're corporate proxy settings from a .pac file, then be sure to use the value for **global** proxy.

Comment: And if you are not behind a corporate firewall on a personal computer sitting at home on a private network???

Answer (score 1):

I lost a day trying to make this work. 
Worked with this steps.

I opened Fiddler and checked the option Rules > Automatically Autenticate.

After, search for file .npmrc, usually in c:\users\ and used it as configuration:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8888
https-proxy=http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8888
http-proxy=http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8888
strict-ssl=false
ca=null
```

Hope help someone!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the similar issue and was using [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) for proxy configuration. In my case `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are taking higher precedence over `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` so be aware of changing all proxy variables.

```
env|grep -i proxy
```

and make sure all of the below proxy variables should point to the same proxy.

```
HTTP-PROXY = "http://localhost:3128"
HTTPS-PROXY = "https://localhost:3128"
HTTPS_PROXY = "http://localhost:3128"
HTTP_PROXY = "http://localhost:3128"
PROXY = "http://localhost:3128"
http-proxy = "http://localhost:3128"
http_proxy = "http://localhost:3128"
https-proxy = "https://localhost:3128/"
https_proxy = "https://localhost:3128"
proxy = "http://localhost:3128/"
```

> I know some variables are unneccessary but I'm not sure which is using what.

Comment: For me I had to change `https-proxy = "https://<IP>:3128/" and https_proxy = "https://<IP>:3128"` to `https-proxy = "http://<IP>:3128/" https_proxy = "http://<IP>:3128"`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error when trying to install Cypress via npm.  I tried many of the above solutions as I am behind a proxy, but was still seeing the same error.  In the end I found that my WIndows system configuration(can be checked by entering 'set' in command prompt) had HTTP and HTTPS proxys set that differed from the ones vonfigure in npm.  I deleted these proxys and it downloaded staright away.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue and none of the above solution worked as I was in protected network.

To overcome this, I have installed "Fiddler" tool from Telerik, after installation start Fiddler and start installation of Protractor again.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you using gnome, and turned off the proxy at the network level, you also need to make sure you don't have proxy enabled in your terminal

```
➜ gconftool-2 -a /system/http_proxy  
 host = http://localhost/
 port = 2000
 use_http_proxy = false
 use_authentication = false
 authentication_password = 
 authentication_user = 
 ignore_hosts = [localhost,127.0.0.0/8]
```

#### You can drop it with

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /system/http_proxy/host ""
gconftool-2 -u /system/http_proxy/port
gconftool-2 -u /system/http_proxy/host
unset http_proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at all of the answers, the one that helped me was providing proxy values in-line with the install command. One of my frustrations was adding the domain to my username. This is **not** needed. I used the following example to install a specific version of Angular:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.3 --proxy "http://username:password@proxy_server:proxy_port" --registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent days trying all the above answers and ensuring I had the proxy and other settings in my node config correct.  All were and it was still failing.  I was/am using a Windows 10 machine and behind a corp proxy.

For some legacy reason, I had `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` set in my user environment variables which overrides the node ones (unknown to me), so correcting these (the `HTTPS_PROXY` one was set to https, so I changed to HTTP) fixed the problem for me.

This is the problem when we can have the Same variables in Multiple places, you don't know what one is being used!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

above code solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar and tried some of the techniques mentioned here. To overcome,

> I performed a cleanup of duplicate entries in c:\users\<user name>\.npmrc

Hope it helps someone.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a VPN on a secure network (like a VPN for working-from-home), you may have an issue with permissions.  For me, I solved this using [**`sudo`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to initialize a ReactJS development environment...

```
sudo npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying all of the above and still having issues, make sure your local path does not contain spaces. (There are ways to allow spaces but mine wasn't set up that way.) In my case, I was using MAMP with a Server Document root of `/Users/myusername/My Site`. Changing this to `/Users/myusername/My-Site` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For windows

If you are not using any proxy (search proxy in start menu search bar to see settings) then

> npm config set proxy null

> npm config set https-proxy null

> npm cache clean

If above does not work, you might need to do it by force, but only if you are sure cache clean does not cause any other installation problem for you

> npm cache clean --force

delete **http_proxy** from environment variables

Try now and it should be fine