# vue init webpack <app-name> failed on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to install a vue project by vue-cli on my Ubuntu 16.04 OS, but I always get this error. I've already searched on google but unfortunately I've found nothing :(

Here is my error on the terminal, I also show you guys the vue, npm and node version, just in case you need to know.

[image: my terminal screenshot]

I'm very beginner about ubuntu and programming stuff, so please tell me the detail if you know something I have to do.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Where are you using vue-cli? As Eric Guan also says, if your network environment is protected by something, you get the error.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i'm not sure if i use proxy or not, how can i chek it in ubuntu?

Comment: i installed vue-cli on my root directory, i guest. i don't know, please helpp

Comment: Seems like you don't have proper access to the Internet. Are certain ports blocked by your provider, etc.?

Comment: again, i'm not sure, i can download some tutorial videos with same wifi connection before and after i got this issue

Comment: What does `env | grep -i proxy` return?

Comment: is that command for ubuntu terminal? if yes, it shows nothing on my terminal @Botje sorry for my very late respon

Comment: [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-econnrefused-10) seems appropriate... For me, both `npm config get proxy` and `npm config get https-proxy` return null.

Comment: thanks man, really appreciate. i'll try it tonight @Botje

Comment: finally its working, first i ran  this commad "npm config list", it shows my http-proxy is filled by something i don't understand, i don't even know who filled that http-proxy, then i ran this commad "npm config set http-proxy null" to set the http-proxy null. Thanks to you @Botje :D

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu 16.4 use the commands:

```
sudo npm i -g vue-cli
vue init webpack test
```

Comment: doesn't work man, i uninstall the vue then reinstall it using sudo npm i -g vue-cli, but i still got the same error