# Inconsistent behavior while installing npm module

Tags: node.js, npm

I am installing a npm module which use `cmake-js` inside it. (I mentioned `cmake-js` just for the information). I am behind a corporate proxy. (I have set proxy settings property). I have already set following configurations.

```
npm config set proxy http://xxxx:yyyy
npm config set https-proxy http://xxxx:yyyy
npm config set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

My `npm` version is 6.4.1. I can build the module without any problem when I switch to node version `8.10.0` using `sudo n 8.10.0`.
But when I move to node `8.0.0` version, I am getting the following error.

```
> cmake-js compile

info TOOL Using Unix Makefiles generator.
info TOOL Using c++11 compiler standard.
info DIST Downloading distribution files.
http DIST   - https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.0.0/SHASUMS256.txt
ERR! OMG tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET
ERR! OMG tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ur-node@1.0.0 install: `cmake-js compile`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ur-node@1.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/malintha/.npm/_logs/2018-09-17T14_23_42_781Z-debug.log
```

It seems like proxy issue, but it is working fine with node 8.10.0

What is the possible reason for this issue? Appreciate any insight to solve this issue.

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-econnrefused-10

Comment: @maxpaj I have already set those configs