# How to fix 'connect ETIMEDOUT' while generating authorization token via azure active directory?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory

actually, I need authorization token so that I can pass it as a header in to run 'create pipeline run' api of azure in node.js.But here I'm again stuck, I'm getting 'connect ETIMEDOUT' error again and again.

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';

var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var resource = 'https://localhost'; // URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid.
var tenant = '';
var applicationId = '';
var clientSecret = '';
var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, applicationId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```

And it shows the following error

```
well that didn't work: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 10.0.0.2:8080
    at ClientRequest.onError (/home/deepti/Desktop/AADL/AADL/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Can anyone point out the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

1.You should identify tenant parameter before authorityUrl.

2.Replace the value of resource with `https://management.azure.com`

Then it works well on my side.
[image]

But these errors will not cause 'connect ETIMEDOUT' error. It seems to be a proxy issue. Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-while-executing-npm-install) will solve your issue.

Comment: using sudo resolved the 'connect ETIMEDOUT' error for me.