# How do I make a request using proxy in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

Im trying to perform a simple request, using a proxy in nodejs with request library.

This is the code:

```
const options = {
    url: "https://www.forextradingbig.com/10-facts-you-must-know-on-online-forex-trading/",
    method: "GET",
    proxy: 'http://86.34.197.6:23500'
};
  
request(options, function(error, response, html) {
    
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      let article_headings = $("h2").text();
      console.log(article_headings);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Error scraping site, please try again");
    }
});
```

And this is the error:

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

I'm using proxies from here: https://free-proxy-list.net/

UPDATE: Getting the same error from two completely different environments: local machine with windows and aws machine with ubuntu 16.

Comment: Working fine. No issues

Comment: @xMayank what do you mean? Each time I run the code, I get the error described above

Comment: `proxy: Url {
    protocol: 'http:',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: '86.34.197.6:23500',
    port: '23500',
    hostname: '86.34.197.6',
    hash: null,
    search: null,
    query: null,
    pathname: '/',
    path: '/',
    href: 'http://86.34.197.6:23500/'`. Working fine

Comment: @xMayank I added exactly the same options you passed, and I continue seeing the same error: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 86.34.197.6:23500
    at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\feder\rather\where-to-see-scraper\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
.....

Comment: @xMayank I tried from my local computer, in windows, and also using a VM in aws, and I get the same error in both environments

Comment: Does this help your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-while-executing-npm-install