# Appium Desktop cant start session error ENOTFOUND

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am just trying to connect with my android emulator on the Windows machine, and I am trying for 4 hours. Tried reinstalling it with lower version 1.15, did not work either

**1. Set up environment variables**
[image: Appium window]

**2. Set up "Desired Capabilities" and press button "Start session". Getting error "ENOTFOUND"**

```
{
  "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
  "platformName": "android",
  "appPackage": "com.android.dialer",
  "appActivity": ".main.impl.MainActivity",
  "noReset": true
}
```

[image]

**3. Message in console**
[image]

**EDIT:**
Tried to find more info through starting java autotests.

```
appiumDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
```

Error screen log:
[image]

full log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/malyez6ejwk7p2f/appium-server-logs.txt?dl=0

**EDIT2**. Today I tried the same as what I did before but with another windows 10 machine and it was a successful result, but I still can't find out how to fix this problem on my main working machine.

It might be a silly mistake somewhere, but I really need help to point it out. Thank you.

Comment: For now, I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, and now everything fine and I can keep studying there, but If someone has encountered the same problem, I would like to go back to Windows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44204395/8877698
The problem was that I had the environment variable **http_proxy**

Answer (score 0):

Some of the values are not set in capabilities. Also try opening all apps as administrator.
I got issues similar to yours solved by this.

```
"platformVersion": "8.0",
"automationName": "UiAutomator2"
```